# AKNodeRecorder in AudioKit doesn't work on the simulator

Tags: swift, audiokit

My app uses AudioKit to generate sound and record it with `AKNodeRecorder`.
Then use `exportAsynchronously` method to create an audio file, but always fails on the simulator.

I tried `mp4`,`caf`,`wav` as output format, but all of them failed.
(Recorder demo in playground doesn't work too.)

On my device(I set `wav` as output), it works fine.
Why it doesn't work on simulator?

I use Xcode9.1, Swift4, AudioKit4.0.3, iPhone6.

Below is my code.

oscillator1 and oscillator2 is connected to `mixer` which is connected to the recorder.

```
func startRecording() {

    recorder = try! AKNodeRecorder(node: mixer, file: tape)

        oscillator1.amplitude = 0.3
        oscillator2.amplitude = 0.3

        AudioKit.start()

        do {

            try recorder.record()
        }
        catch {

            print("Couldn't record")
        }
}



func stopRecording() {

        recorder.stop()

        tape.exportAsynchronously(name: "audio",
                              baseDir: .temp,
                              exportFormat: .wav) { _,_ in  }

        AudioKit.stop()
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's not working?

Comment: Yes, I add my code on my post. If you need any other information, tell me.